# How can we use ChromeDriver, IEDriver, GeckoDriver without selenium in python?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am looking for a way to use web drivers (ChromeDriver, IEDriver, GeckoDriver etc., all together) with my native python app such that, the app will figure out the browser, and choose the driver accordingly, and will do some actions (like click an element or get data). I want to do the task in python without using selenium

Comment: This is not possible. ChromeDriver, et. al, are products of Selenium WebDriver. Why do you not want to use Selenium? If you are testing a web app and want multi-browser support, it is THE tool to use. Selenium supports Python.

Comment: Is there any other way to interact with browsers for automation?? I mean tools like UI Path wouldn't be using selenium, and I wish to make something from scratch as well. It'll be great if you can provide with a solution. The only solution that I have implemented so far is to create a google extension for activities like inspect, and click but it have two issues : 1) My whole code will be public and easily accessible 2) I can't make a manual click like UI Path does.

Comment: There is Cypress.io, it does not use Selenium, but uses Javascript, and has no cross-browser functionality. There is WatiN, or WatiR. WatiN uses .NET, and WatiR uses Ruby. 

There are others out there, but seriously, the best tool I have come across is Selenium Webdriver. Yes, it has flaws, however, for cross-browser testing, it really is the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would theoretically be possible to use the driver executables without Selenium. All WebDriver implementations operate using the same mechanism. That mechanism is starting an HTTP server running locally, and listening on a well-known set of end points (URLs) for HTTP requests containing well-defined JSON bodies.

It’s fully possible to even start a WebDriver implementation like `IEDriverServer.exe`, `geckodriver`, or `chromedriver` and automate the browser even using a tool like cURL, so using a Python HTTP client library and JSON parser is certainly in the realm of the possible. However, doing so requires a fairly thorough understanding of the protocol used in communicating with the driver, and gaining that understanding is distinctly non-trivial. In fact, use of that protocol without needing to know the details of it is one of the very reasons for Selenium’s existence.

While what you say you want to do is *possible*, I would by no means call it *recommended*. Attempting to go down that road seems like a lot of effort for a very marginal benefit, when you consider you need to worry about lifetime of the executable process you spawn, proper formatting of the HTTP request bodies, and handling all of the potential responses from the remote end. You’d be reinventing a whole lot of things that Selenium already does for you. Your question doesn’t show any indication of *why* you don’t want to use Selenium, so it’s difficult to provide any further guidance as to alternatives or mitigations to the things you find objectionable about it.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Actually, I am trying to create my own RPA Tool, and I am looking a solution, for automating web, and I don't want to use any library like selenium. I created an extension that does almost everything, but the problem with extension is that whole my source code is visible, and I don't want that. Can you give any solution?

Comment: I don’t know what an “RPA Tool” is, I’m afraid, so I can offer no advice on how to create one. Moreover, you still haven’t answered the question of why you don’t want to use Selenium beyond what amount to, “I just don’t want to.” To be sure, that’s a perfectly valid reason, but can you clarify whether that is the only reason, or if there is some other deficiency you’re trying to overcome?

Comment: I just want to create each and everything from scratch (everything that is possible), no other reason. RPA Tool is an automation tool you can google about it. What I want is to interact with my browser such that I want to open a browser click an element and get it's xpath, selectors or whatever possible so that I can repeat the same task again and again without any human involvement. One solution I found is to use extension for everything but I don't want my code to be open to all neither I want to use someone else's. Can you give a solution for this task?